# Calling Web API from client

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have to pass the following inputs from the windows client to  Web API. Currently i have created a class to hold all these inputs. Since it is a web API, can i move it into an array or dictionay  and pass to the web API? How do i call it from client, since i have a list of string also need to send for the IRN parameter?

```
 public class RTestRequest
    {
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }

        public string AccountNo { get; set; }

        public List<string> IRN{ get; set; }

        public bool ALRequired { get; set; }

        public string Loc { get; set; }

        public string AMR{ get; set; }

        public bool TranscationData { get; set; }
    }
```

in the server, i have

```
public Response GetOffers([FromUri] TestRequest Request)
{
        code inside....
}
```

From my Windows client app(Not using JSON or client call for this) how do i pass this to server?
And is that the correct implementation in server? I am trying to do async calls from Console application in VS 2010.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found a solution to this. Current API Service code remains same.

client code will have request params in a string and pass this as a param to the Service. Done. Auto model binding will trigger